# Output 256-bit using Argon2 hasher

Tags: python, argon2-cffi

I am trying to generate a 256-bit output using Argon2 password hasher. The function take s a `hash_len` parameter which I set to 32. Thinking that 32 bytes equals 256 bits.

Why does Argon2 output the length of 43, and not 32?

```
from argon2 import PasswordHasher

password = "abc123"
salt = b'b8b17dbde0a2c67707342c459f6225ed'

hasher = PasswordHasher(
    salt_len=len(salt),
    hash_len=32,
)
hasherOutput = hasher.hash(password, salt = salt)
hash = hasherOutput.split('$')[-1]

print(len(hash))

# Output: 43
# Expected: 32
```

Comment: Is it perhaps Base64 encoded? 256 bits / 6 bits per byte = 42 bytes, at least when encoded like that. A hexdigest equivalent would be 64 bytes.

Comment: @tadman Example output of variable `hash` is `TJ4lev0MJEc+UdBtvmZkFQ`.

Comment: That looks very base 64 encoded.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that like the comments pointed out, the string was indeed Base64-encoded. Trying to decode it using `binascii.a2b_base64()` failed until I appended "==" to the input.

Comment: Storing it without the padding makes sense from an efficiency perspective. Some Base64 decoders are indifferent to padding, while others are (annoyingly) strict.